# Match Some Text with Regex

Tags: regex

with this text ->

```
<p>sadadsadsad @Jack&nbsp;</p>
<p>@John Rich &amp; Sarah&nbsp;</p><p>sadadsadsadsadsadasd @Junior Cam AND Ken&nbsp;</p>
<p>
<br></p><p>asdsadasdasdasd #12345-S Company&nbsp;asdsadasdasd @Tom Mer AND Grace&nbsp;</p><p>asdadsadasd @Milo Elisa&nbsp;</p>
```

May I know what is the correct regex to pick up the following text :

- @Jack
- @John Rich & Sarah
- @Junior Cam AND Ken
- #12345-S Company
- @Milo Elisa
- @Tom Mer AND Grace

I have this regex but seems its not getting it right.

> /([@|#|!].+ )/gm

Thank you...

Comment: Can you show more examples? these four examples seem not enough to determine the actual pattern you want. e.g., why is `@Jack` omitted?

Comment: Basically all text that comes along with a @ or # or !. Includes @Jack. I apologize

Comment: @felix You can add that to the question, and you missed out `@Tom Mer AND Grace` too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all names are guaranteed to end with `&nbsp;`, then you may try:

```
/([@#].+?)(?=&nbsp;)/gm
```

And later you can replace `&amp;` with `&`

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `|` inside `[]`, try this

```
/[@#!]([\w \-]|&amp; )+/gm
```

`[@#!]` for the prefix

`[\w \-]|&amp;` for names, numbers, spaces, `-` or `&amp;`

Comment: Cool...however its still missing the @John Rich &amp; Sarah ? How to match that too. Thanks

Comment: @felix You are right, sorry I missed that out. Although you got your answer already, I have updated my alternative answer